# How does the binary size impact of a feature written in React Native compare to native Android?

Tags: android, react-native

Assuming an Android app already has React Native in it, I am curious how the binary size of the app would grow for a feature written in React Native vs standard Android/Java?

I have a theory that a feature written in JavaScript (assuming all native bridges to build it are already in the app) will impact the binary size less than an equivalent Java implementation. The same feature written in Java will compile to many Java bytecode operations (and then compressed in APK) while the equivalent JavaScript will be minified directly in the release binary (and then compressed in APK).

As an example, take this Java code:

```
public int simpleSwitch(String stringOne) {
    switch (stringOne) {
        case "a":
            return 0;
        case "b":
            return 2;
        case "c":
            return 3;
        default:
            return 4;
    }
}
```

Per [this page](http://blog.jamesdbloom.com/JavaCodeToByteCode_PartOne.html#switch) the Java bytecode would be 111 bytes. The minified JavaScript would be 86 bytes:

```
switch(stringOne){case"a":return 0;case"b":return 2;case"c":return 3;default:return 4}
```

---

As a counter example, take this Java code:

```
outer:
for (int i = 2; i < 1000; i++) {
    for (int j = 2; j < i; j++) {
        if (i % j == 0)
            continue outer;
    }
    System.out.println (i);
}
```

Per [this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_bytecode#Example), it is 44 bytes in bytecode. The equivalent code in JavaScript, minified is:

```
i:for(var i=2;1e3>i;i++){for(var j=2;i>j;j++)if(i%j==0)continue i;console.log(i)}
```

Which is 82 bytes.

I also wonder if minified JavaScript compresses better/worse than Java bytecode in the APK, which may affect this theory.